# Java Sort multiple arrays based of another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am looking to do an ascending sort 7 arrays, based of a the values of one of them and then print the final array using a loop inside of a method. the array values are entered by the user and will contain at least one set of data but no more than 5 sets.

My code so far is below, its the basic structure of a selection sort as I was requested to use that, I am looking to do the ascending sort off of the array simp (stands for simple interest) but I cannot figure out how to get all the other arrays to move with it retain the values.

any ideas on the loop method to use for this?

```
public static void sort(double[] amount, double[] iRate, int[] term, double[] simp, double[] month, double[] daily, double[] weekly)
  {

      for (int i=0;i<simp.length-1;i++)
      {
            int minindex=i;
            for (int j=i+1;j<simp.length;j++)
            {
                if(simp[minindex]>simp[j])
                    minindex=j;
            }
            double temp = simp[minindex];
            simp[minindex]=simp[i];
            simp[i]= temp;
      }

}
```

**Example Run**

```
[Line #]    [Principal Amount]  Interest rate   term    simple  monthly     weekly    daily
1            $1,375.00                1.18%         7    9.4244   9.4522      9.4557    9.4567
2             $100.00                 3.25%         6     1.625    1.636      1.6377    1.6382
3             $100.00                 3.25%         12     3.25   3.2988      3.3023    3.3032

[Line #]    [Principal Amount]  Interest rate   term    simple   monthly    weekly    daily
1             $100.00                 3.25%        6       1.62    1.636     1.6377    1.6382
2             $100.00                 3.25%       12       3.25    3.2988    3.3023    3.3032
3           $1,375.00                 1.18%        7      9.4244   9.4522    9.4557    9.4567
```

Comment: Why bother to write your own implemention of selection sort instead of just using the built in sort from the Java library? Is this homework?

Comment: indeed it is, and i am stuck on it ive got it all done except this  part of sorting all the arrays off of one

Comment: It is allowed to post homework questions here, but please read this first: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I have seen that and I have made good faith effort the last 5 days. Full code available here [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71927/InterestCalculatorBatch.java](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71927/InterestCalculatorBatch.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way to do it using your existing code is to swap elements in all arrays whenever you are swapping elements in `simp`:

```
double temp = simp[minindex];
simp[minindex]=simp[i];
simp[i]= temp;

temp = iRate[minindex];
iRate[minindex]=iRate[i];
iRate[i]= temp;

.
.
.
```

This isn't the most elegant way. The OO way to do it would be to have an object that has `amount, iRate, term...` as members and sort an array of these objects.

Comment: As messy as this way may seem it did work for what I needed though i did still remain with trouble after calling the method while trying to display it all neatly but thats ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with all fields inside:

```
 class Entity implements Comparable<Entity> {
      double simp;
      double amount;
      double rate;
      ...
      // construct each instance taking the next line from 
      // the arrays or doubles

      // implement compareTo
      public int compareTo(Entity entity) {
         // compare only the field you need
         return Double.compare(simp, entity.simp); 
      }
   }
```

Then build an array of entities based on your seven arrays and sort it using `Arrays.sort()`
At the end you can copy data back to the arrays of doubles, or simply print the contents directly from the Entity[].